# Automatically Updated Canvases Are Blurry

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have this application that automatically updates when I make a change to a canvas which is great but when I add text or move things around the static canvases get blurry and are unusable. You'll notice that when you add text it looks fine in the first canvas but in the others, it becomes more blurry as you move it around. It also has this weird behavior where you have to click the IText object to deselect it/stop dragging it around. Please see my example below:

```js
var canvas = [];
canvas.push(new fabric.Canvas('c0'));
for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
  canvas.push(new fabric.StaticCanvas('sc' + i));
}

function dropText() {
  var text = new fabric.IText('Type here...', {
    fontSize: 27,
    top: 10,
    left: 10,
    lockUniScaling: true
  });
  canvas[0].add(text);
}

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  fill: '#ff0000',
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  id: 1
});
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  fill: '#ffff00',
  radius: 50,
  left: 150,
  top: 150,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  id: 2
});

canvas[0].on('object:added', onModified);
canvas[0].on('object:modified', onModified);
canvas[0].on('object:scaling', onModified);
canvas[0].on('object:moving', onModified);
canvas[0].add(rect, circle);

function onModified(option) {
  var ob = option.target;
  var index = canvas[0].getObjects().indexOf(ob);
  for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    if (!ob) {
      canvas[i].remove(ob);
      canvas[i].insertAt(option.target, index);
    } else {
      canvas[i].add(option.target);
    }
  }
};

$('#update').click(function() {
  var json = JSON.stringify(canvas[0]);
  for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    canvas[i].loadFromJSON(json);
  }
});

$('#save').click(function() {
  html2canvas($('#imagesave'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      // toDataURL defaults to png, so we need to request a jpeg, then convert for file download.
      a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace("image/jpeg", "image/octet-stream");
      a.download = 'myfile.jpg';
      a.click();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
}

td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

#imagesave {
  background-color: white;
  height: 637.5px;
  width: 825px;
  padding-left: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.21/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="dropText();" class="dropdown-item">Add Text</button><button id="save">Save</button>


<div id="imagesave">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <canvas id="c0" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc1" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc2" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc3" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc4" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc5" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc6" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc7" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad,I haven't thought of this situation. You need to clone the object before adding to other canvases.

```
var ob = option.target;
var index = canvas[0].getObjects().indexOf(ob);
ob.clone(function(obj){
  for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    canvas[i].insertAt(obj, index, true);
  }
});
```

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = [];
canvas.push(new fabric.Canvas('c0'));
for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
  canvas.push(new fabric.StaticCanvas('sc' + i));
}

function dropText() {
  var text = new fabric.IText('Type here...', {
    fontSize: 27,
    top: 10,
    left: 10,
  });
  canvas[0].add(text);
}

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  fill: '#ff0000',
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  id: 1
});
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  fill: '#ffff00',
  radius: 50,
  left: 150,
  top: 150,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  id: 2
});

canvas[0].on('object:added', onModified);
canvas[0].on('object:modified', onModified);
canvas[0].on('object:scaling', onModified);
canvas[0].on('object:moving', onModified);
canvas[0].add(rect, circle);

function onModified(option) {
  var ob = option.target;
  var index = canvas[0].getObjects().indexOf(ob);
  ob.clone(function(obj){
    for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
      canvas[i].insertAt(obj, index, true);
    }
  });
};

$('#update').click(function() {
  var json = JSON.stringify(canvas[0]);
  for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    canvas[i].loadFromJSON(json);
  }
});

$('#save').click(function() {
  html2canvas($('#imagesave'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      // toDataURL defaults to png, so we need to request a jpeg, then convert for file download.
      a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace("image/jpeg", "image/octet-stream");
      a.download = 'myfile.jpg';
      a.click();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
}

td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

#imagesave {
  background-color: white;
  height: 637.5px;
  width: 825px;
  padding-left: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.js"></script>
<button onclick="dropText();" class="dropdown-item">Add Text</button><button id="save">Save</button>


<div id="imagesave">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <canvas id="c0" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc1" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc2" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc3" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc4" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc5" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc6" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc7" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: @codeforever, I guess in 1.7.21 itext editing gives error, so used 1.7.22 instead

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried either clearing the canvas between drawing the text or setting the `context.imageSmoothingEnabled` to false?